# How to initialize an array inside of a tree node in my constructor?

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor, tree

I am building a general tree in C++. I've simplified my code just to get the idea of what I'm doing. Essentially, I want to store a char array in each of my tree nodes. I know the size of the array and the size and contents of the array will be the same for every node.

My question is how to initialize the array in my tree constructor? Sample setup:

```
class Tree{
public:
    Tree();

private:

struct Node{
    Node* lchild;
    Node* mchild;
    Node* rchild;
    Node* parent;
    char arr[5];
};

Node* root;

};
```

So in my constructor I initialize my root as a new node and all my pointers to nullptr.

```
Tree::Tree(){
    root = new Node;
    root->parent = nullptr;
    root->lchild = nullptr;
    root->mchild = nullptr;
    root->rchild = nullptr;
    root->arr[0] = 'a', root->arr[1] = 'b', root->arr[2] = 'c', root->arr[3] = 'd', root->arr[4] = 'e';
}
```

Say I want to initialize my char array to contain `'a','b','c','d','e'` Is there a better way than doing it manually? I'm using VS 2012. From what I have read it doesn't fully support C++11.

Comment: It is bad style to have a class be initialized by someone else. Instead, `Node` should have a constructor (or default values for its parameters), so that `root = new Node;` or `root = new Node(args...);` does all the initialization you need.

Comment: what speaks against `Tree::Tree() : arr("abcd") { ...}`?

Comment: and also: If you are using "arr" as a string, you are forgetting the termination symbol - char[5] can only hold the string "abcd" - because the 5th character is the \0 terminator.

Answer (score 1):

One way:

```
memcpy( arr, "abcde", 5 );
```

Comment: Note: the `5` is correct as-is. The array is declared as `arr[5]`. Not all `char` arrays are C (null-terminated) strings.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using c++11, so just write:

```
struct Node{
    Node* lchild;
    Node* mchild;
    Node* rchild;
    Node* parent;
    char arr[5] { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using C++11, I will just suggest to use `std::array<char, 5> arr` instead of `char arr[5]`. It can be used in this way:

```
#include <array>

class Tree{
public:
    Tree();

private:

struct Node{
    Node* lchild;
    Node* mchild;
    Node* rchild;
    Node* parent;
    std::array<char, 5> arr;
};

Node* root;

};

Tree::Tree(){
    root = new Node;
    root->parent = nullptr;
    root->lchild = nullptr;
    root->mchild = nullptr;
    root->rchild = nullptr;
    root->arr = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'};

}
```

Comment: When i tried it that way, I got compiler errors. All from `root->arr = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' };` syntax error : '{'                                                               syntax error : missing ';' before '{'                                                                  syntax error : missing ';' before '}'

Comment: Which compiler? I used g++ 5.2.0.

Comment: @user5447431You are correct: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx
You need VS2013 in order to use Initializer lists.